# Are there any known workarounds for the January 2014 "sound-loop" crash?

Tags: pc, battlefield-4

There's a [nasty bug](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/battlefield-4-pc-bug-causing-game-to-freeze-enter-sound-loop/1100-6417893/) for BF4 affecting a lot of people right now, which causes the game to crash and loop the intro-sound when attempting to join a game.

DICE has said they're working on a fix, but in the meanwhile, are there any known workarounds?

Comment: personally I don't think there is any workaround. Otherwise it would be posted somewhere by now

Comment: Any known workaround would be all over the forums and various gaming news sites, so it's safe to assume not.

Comment: There is a patch which will be released by the time this bounty expires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like they [released a patch for this issue](http://www.ibtimes.com/battlefield-4-problems-ea-dice-launches-bf4-updates-pc-xbox-one-1557803) literally minutes after I created the bounty.

Sigh.

Comment: but does it actually fix it?

Comment: @3ventic: Yep, I've confirmed that it's working now.

Comment: Works for me as well.  Played Metro for the first time sans crash last night.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like they [released a patch](http://www.ibtimes.com/battlefield-4-problems-ea-dice-launches-bf4-updates-pc-xbox-one-1557803) for this issue literally minutes after you created the bounty.

That being said, the patch is causing further problems causing [this to crash too](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf4/forum/threadview/2955064774794328459/). You can fix this manually before waiting for a patch by:

1. Go into your game directory (dir:\Program files(x86)\Origin Games\Battlefield 4)
2. If you have a “user.cfg” file, open it in notepad.
3. Delete the command line “UI.DrawEnable 1”
4. Save the file
5. Start the game